# Using Local Dependencies with Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

Is there a way to get Homebrew to recognize that a dependency is already installed outside of Homebrew?

For example, I prefer to install programming languages via a tool like `asdf/nvm/rvm/etc` so I can easily manage multiple versions. However, if a Homebrew formula lists node, for example, as a dependency, Homebrew will install another version of node that will never actually get used.

Can I tell it I already have node installed?

Answer (score 0):

`Homebrew` is build/distribution tool, it does not manage user specific stuff nor it does have permissions to do it.

brew install process is in [install.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb), you can check out more for details.

All the core team maintained formula are in [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/) and cask formula are in [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask).